# Getting warnings when assigning characters to a 2d array declared using malloc in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am learning how to use malloc to create a dynamic array. I am trying to assign characters to it and then print them. The program works when I run it, however I keep getting these warnings:

Location (1): warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'char *' from 'int' [-Wint-conversion]

Location(2): warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]

How do I fix this, and why do I keep getting this warnings?

```
int main(void) {  
     char **board = (char **) malloc(26*26*sizeof(char));

    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        *(board + i) = i + 'a'; //location (1)
        printf("%c\n", *(board + i)); //location (2)
    }
    free(board);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: There is no 2D array. A pointer is not an array.

Answer (score 1):

The type of

```
*(board + i)
```

is a `char*` and you are trying to assign a value of type `int` to this. This is what the compiler is complaining about in both cases - `char*` is not an `int`!

I would suggest that as you know the size to be fixed (26x26) that you simply use a normal 2D array

```
char board[26][26];
```

as there does not seem to be a need to use dynamic allocation.

If you want to persist with your approach using `malloc`, first create an array of 26 `char*` and then assign a dynamic array of 26 `char` to each one.

Something like this

```
char* board[26];
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
{
    board[26] = malloc(26*sizeof(char));
}
```

You will also need to have 2 loops to populate the table as a single loop from 0 to 25 is not going to populate everything.

Comment: Thanks a lot this really helps.